# Execute dynamically created array of observables in series

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs, rxjs5

I am working on a project (Angular2) where I am creating Observables dynamically and putting them in an array

```
var ObservableArray : Observable<any>[] = [];
//filling up Observable array dynamically
for (var i = 0; i < this.mainPerson.children.length; i++) {       
ObservableArray.push(Observable.fromPromise(this.determineFate(this.mainPerson.children[i])));
  }
}


var finalObservable: Observable<any> = Observable.concat(ObservableArray);

finalObservable
  .subscribe( data => {
    //here  I expected to execute determineFate() for all observables inside array  
    console.log("determine fate resolved data returned [" + data + "]");
  }, error => {
    console.error("error on Age Year for Characters")
  },() => {  
    //Here I expect this gets executed only when all Observables inside my array finishes 
    console.log("determine fate resolved data returned COMPLETED");
    //DB call
  });

  determineFate(..): Promise<boolean> {
       ...
       return either true / false if success or error;

 }
```

I want to execute all observables in a series (`forkJoin` seems to run in parallel - so used concat). Once all observables are executed, want to execute some DB related code. But it seems my code inside 'Completed' block does not wait for all Observables to finish. How can I achieve this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't understand how `forkJoin` wasn't useful in this situation. `forkJoin` will for all your observables to finish. Then you can run your db query. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: determineFate() uses some 'this' variables which are getting overwritten by parallel threads. I have already tried forkJoin() but due to above issue, need to execute all in series.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using `Observable.concat(ObservableArray)` will just flatten the array and emit each Observable from `ObservableArray` one by one. Btw, using the static version of `concat` makes sense only with two or more parameters (see http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-concat).

Instead you can iterate the array of Observables and wait until they complete one by one with the `concatAll()` operator.

This example simulates your use-case:

```
var observableArray = [];
// filling up Observable array dynamically
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  observableArray.push(Observable.of('Value ' + i));
}

Observable.from(observableArray)
  .concatAll()
  .subscribe(console.log, null, () => console.log('completed'));
```

The `Observable.from()` emits each Observable separately and `concatAll()` subscribes to each one of them in the order they were emitted.

This demo prints to console the following output:

```
Value 0
Value 1
Value 2
Value 3
Value 4
Value 5
Value 6
Value 7
Value 8
Value 9
completed
```