# How to catch all different responses from an array of observables?

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

In Angular I have an array of observables. I want to execute all of those observables but also handle all of the different results. When I try to implement this using `forkJoin` or `combineLatest` I just get a single (error) response in the test scenario where I have 4 observables which all failed.

Example:

```
const callsToExecute = [];
vehicles.forEach(vehicle => {
    callsToExecute.push(this.createRequest(vehicle.id));
)};

forkJoin(callsToExecute).subscribe(result => {}, error => {/** single response error */});
```

How can I catch all different responses?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43133405/execute-dynamically-created-array-of-observables-in-series

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try the following method to catch errors for individual observables :

```
const callsToExecute = [];
callsToExecute.push(of('Hello').pipe(map((res) => res), catchError(e => of('Oops! 1'))));
callsToExecute.push(of('Hello 2').pipe(map((res) => res), catchError(e => of('Oops! 2'))));
callsToExecute.push(of('Hello 3').pipe(map((res) => res), catchError(e => of('Oops! 3'))));
const example = forkJoin(
  callsToExecute
);
const subscribe = example.subscribe(val => console.log(val));
```

I have created stackBlitz examples [Example1](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-amt3jt) [Example2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/fork-join-example-angular-5-6-7-gftid8?file=src/app/app.component.ts)